# Update a table after insert data on another table using trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have to update a column in table_b when a row inserted to table_a.

**Query**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Update
ON table_a FOR INSERT
AS 
UPDATE table_b
SET Sold_Qty=inserted.qty
WHERE OrdNo=inserted.OrdNo;
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_Update, Line 6
The multi-part identifier "inserted.OrdNo" could not be bound.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in place of the `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE table_b
SET Sold_Qty=inserted.qty
FROM table_b b
INNER JOIN inserted ON b.OrdNo=inserted.OrdNo;
```

Comment: @Ullas You're welcome. My initial comment to the OP was due to my misreading *bound* for *found* :-)